# Dynamic assignment using data.table `:=`

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to set a series of values in data.table using the below code:

```
db[, `:=`(paste("PAID", c("A", "B", "C"), sep = "_") = .SD * COST,
          paste("PAID_NET", c("A", "B", "C"), sep = "_") = .SD * COST * (1 - TAX))
         , .SDcols = paste("PRICE", c("A", "B", "C"), sep = "_")]
```

These would work if there wasn't a `paste` involved, but there is, so it doesn't.

Desired behaivour is that 6 new columns are created, PAID_A, PAID_B, PAID_C, PAID_NET_A, PAID_NET_B, PAID_NET_C, based on SOLD_A, SOLD_B, SOLD_C, COST and TAX.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the names on the lhs of `=` wouldn't work as expected. We can instead do

```
nm1 <- paste("PAID", c("A", "B", "C"), sep = "_")
nm2 <- paste("PAID_NET", c("A", "B", "C"), sep = "_") 
nm3 <- paste("PRICE", c("A", "B", "C"), sep = "_")
db[, c(nm1, nm2) :=  c(.SD * COST,
         .SD * COST * (1 - TAX)),
     , .SDcols = nm3]
```

---

Or another option is `setNames`

```
db[, `:=`(setNames(.SD * COST, .SD * COST * (1 - TAX), c(nm1, nm2))),
         .SDcols = nm3]
```

Comment: You've made me realise that this is probably an issue with `list` - 
`list(paste("a", "b") = 3)` also fails with the same error. Thanks.